# What's a practical use-case for "address of array"?

Tags: c++, pointers

(Disclaimer: Pointers in C++ is a VERY popular topic and so I'm compelled to believe that someone before me has already raised this point. However, I wasn't able to find another reference. Please correct me and feel free to close this thread if I'm wrong.)

I've come across lots of examples that distinguish between pointer to first element of array and pointer to the array itself. Here's one program and its output:

```
//pointers to arrays
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr[10]  = {};
    int *p_start = arr;
    int (*p_whole)[10] = &arr;

    cout << "p_start is " << p_start <<endl;
    cout << "P_whole is " << p_whole <<endl;

    cout << "Adding 1 to both . . . " <<endl;

    p_start += 1;
    p_whole += 1;

    cout << "p_start is " << p_start <<endl;
    cout << "P_whole is " << p_whole <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
p_start is 0x7ffc5b5c5470
P_whole is 0x7ffc5b5c5470
Adding 1 to both . . . 
p_start is 0x7ffc5b5c5474
P_whole is 0x7ffc5b5c5498
```

So, as expected, adding 1 to both gives different results. But I'm at a loss to see a practical use for something like `p_whole`. Once I have the address of the entire array-block, which can be obtained using `arr` as well, what can I do with such a pointer?

Comment: In C++ there is no use , as you could use reference to array instead. Reference to array is quite useful (e.g. the canonical implementation of getting the dimension of an array based on its name).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For single arrays, I don't think there's much point to it. Where it becomes useful is with multi-dimensional arrays, which are arrays of arrays. A pointer to one of the sub-arrays is a pointer to the row, and incrementing it gets you a pointer to the next row. In contrast, a pointer to the first element of the inner array is a pointer to a single element, and incrementing it gets you the next element.

Comment: Yes, makes sense! This would make iteration so much better.

Comment: @dotslash And allocation. If you ever see someone calling an `int **` a "two-dimensional array", correct them, and tell them to `malloc(COLS * sizeof(int[ROWS]))` instead (where the base pointer type will be `int (*)[ROWS]`). Use contiguous memory, save the cache!

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Thanks for the tip! Didn't get the "save the cache" part, though. Please explain. :)

Comment: @dotslash allocating one contiguous chunk of memory (which can be treated as a true 2D array) instead of using a pointer-to-pointers has multiple benefits. The first one is cache locality: the contiguous slice of memory is, well… contiguous. The system will be able to identify that fact and cache it easily, hence it'll be faster to access (whereas accessing independent memory blocks can cause cache misses). Second, accessing array elements will need less indirections (one pointer dereference rather than two of them). Third, it will need less allocations and deallocations (1 versus `1 + COLS`).

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant it does fewer indirections, but it replaces them with multiplications, since the row index has to be multiplied by the number of columns to get the row offset. But you're right about locality, although if you allocate all the rows in a loop most of them may end up being adjacent. So it's probably best to make the decision about 2-D vs array of pointers based on what's best for the application design, otherwise it's premature optimization.

Comment: @Barmar since a 2D array is also *simpler* (to create and manage) than a bunch of pointers, and conveys intent better, I see no reason *not* to use it from the beginning. At the beginning, it's not about optimization, it's about defensive programming. (Of course if one needs different semantics, that's another question.) – But is a multiplication really a big problem? An uncached memory access is *way* slower on modern CPUs than a multiplication (especially if the multiplier is a power of 2, as it often is.)

Comment: You can only use a 2-D array if you know the array dimensions statically. Sometimes you need to use an array of pointers because you're allocating the whole array dynamically. C has variable-length arrays, but C++ doesn't.

Comment: @Barmar Don't twist my words! That's why I wrote "Of course if one needs different semantics, that's another question".

Answer (score 2):

`int (*)[10]` is a "stronger" type than `int*` as it keeps size of the array,
so you may pass it to function without passing additional size parameter:

```
void display(const int(*a)[10]) // const int (&a)[10] seems better here
{
    for (int e : *a) {
        std::cout << " " << e;
    }
}
```

versus

```
void display(const int* a, std::size_t size) // or const int* end/last
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        std::cout << " " << a[i];
    }
}
```